# why not complete line?

Tags: modeling, vertices

[image]

when I set ctrl+R the vertices dont appear around of model,please explain

Answer (score 2):

Because as it crosses a triangle, Blender doesn't know where it is supposed to continue, that's one of the reasons you should use quads as much as possible, with quads there would be no ambiguity.

But if you want to keep your topology as it is and quickly create your edge loop you can use the knife tool.

[image]